# Convert an ASP.NET XSD (Dataset) to Windows Forms

Tags: asp.net, winforms

Is there a way to convert an XSD ASP.NET file to a Windows Forms XSD? Is there a tool for this? I am sure it can be done if you went through each file, but is there an easy conversion (maybe in Visual Studio)?

Comment: What makes you think there's a difference? Have you tried just adding the dataset to your forms project?

Comment: yes i have tried. there is a difference. it just shows up and opens as an xml file.  the connection strings are not stored in the web.config like asp.net (from what i understand). i know that copying the file doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I've created two datasets in a Windows Forms project and in ASP.NET project and compared them (with Visual Studio 2010). They were almost identical, except of two points:

1. Windows Forms generated SQL statements with optimistic concurrency while ASP.NET didn't
2. `Connection` elements differed (because of setting source)

I think it's possible to write a simple XSLT to change the `Connection` element and leave everything else as is.

Also, when you adding an existing .xsd dataset file, you should set `Custom Tool` to `MSDataSetGenerator` in file properties in Visual Studio, or Visual Studiowon't refresh the `.Designer.cs` file.

**(UPDATE)** Here's a simple example (unfinished) of such an XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd"
                xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
                xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop"
                xmlns:msds="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="msds:Connection">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="AppSettingsObjectName">Settings</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="AppSettingsPropertyName">
                <xsl:value-of select="@AppSettingsPropertyName" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <!-- TODO: add other attributes... -->
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think that it is more complex than that.  Note that windows forms adds (not just .xsd and .xss as ASP.NET does), but also whatever_the_filename_is.Designer.cs (or .vb).

Comment: @Jason Reed, no it's not more complex than that. .xss & .xsc files related to designer layout and saved shape positions in designer view, so you can delete and it won't affect functionality. And *.Designer.cs is produced from xsd by MSDataSetGenerator. In fact, ASP.NET project contains it too, but Visual Web Developer Express -- doesn't (still AFAIK it's generated in runtime). In short, you need to add __ONLY__ .xsd file, select it in solution view, open properties window and type `MSDataSetGenerator` to custom tool property. Also you need to change Connection attrs. That should be enough.

Comment: @Jason Reed, you can easily check that .Designer.cs is (re)generated by VS: open a winforms solution, add a DataSet, then delete ddataset's .Designer.cs file. Then right-click the xsd file in solution view and select 'Run Custom Tool'. .Designer.cs file will reappear.